# What approach, choosing from Barnes and Bloor from SSK, or Kitcher from ESK, best described current practices in economics

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Can someone help me with this question, because I can't get the answer myself, would like to start a discussion as well.

SSK is the sociology of scientific knowledge and ESK is the economics of scientific knowledge.

My view is that it's more ESK because they tend to create incentives such as prices (like the Nobel Prizes) in order to motivate scientists.

Comment: This is more of a question and answer site than a discussion site. I am unfamiliar with the acronyms SSK amd ESK. What do they stand for? If there is any text where the question comes from this would help give it context. Also what is your current view on the matter? Welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: SSK is the sociology of scientific knowledge and ESK is the Economics of scientific knowledge. My view is that its more of the ESK because they tend to create incentives such as prices (like the nobel prizes) in order to motivate scientists

Comment: Thank you.  I added your comment to the question. Hopefully this context will help keep the question open.

Comment: Did you hear about this in a philosophy class you are taking? Are Barnes and Bloor philosophers?  Or is there some link to philosophy that you can make more clear?